# How to make nested collapsible tableview i swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have some designs in which parents and their children both are collapsible. I have achieved for parent level using table view but for its children how would I implement its expanded cell. Should I load another custom view cell or should I change in the current cell, I don't have any idea. if anybody has some idea please help me out on this.

```
   // Model Class
class WorkoutTemplate {
    var folderName:String
    var workoutType: [WorkoutType]
    init(folderName: String, workoutType: [WorkoutType]) {
        self.folderName = folderName
        self.workoutType = workoutType
    }
}
class WorkoutType {
    var workoutCategoryName: String // Basic Full Body
    var totalWorkouts : [Workout]
    init(workoutCategoryName: String, totalWorkouts: [Workout] ) {
        self.workoutCategoryName = workoutCategoryName
        self.totalWorkouts = totalWorkouts
    }
}
class  Workout{
    var workoutName: String
    var reps:Int = 0
    var sets:Int = 0
    init(workoutName: String, reps: Int, sets: Int) {
        self.workoutName = workoutName
        self.reps = reps
        self.sets = sets
    }
    
}



// Controller class
import UIKit

class AddWorkoutViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView?
    var data = [WorkoutTemplate]()
    var sectionIsExpanded = [false, false, false]
    private let headerIdentifier = "WorkoutTemplateHeaderCell"
    private let cellIdentifier = "AddWorkoutCategoryCell"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let workout = Workout(workoutName: "Squat", reps: 10, sets: 9)
        let workout2 = Workout(workoutName: "Bench press", reps: 6, sets: 7)
        let workout3 = Workout(workoutName: "Dunmbell lunge", reps: 12, sets: 78)
        
        let workoutType = WorkoutType(workoutCategoryName: "Basic full body", totalWorkouts: [workout, workout2, workout3])
        
        let workoutTemplate = WorkoutTemplate(folderName: "My Workout Template", workoutType: [workoutType, workoutType])
        
        data.append(workoutTemplate)
        data.append(workoutTemplate)
        data.append(workoutTemplate)
        
        tableView?.reloadData()
        
        
    }
}

extension AddWorkoutViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // First will always be header
        let sectiondata = data[section]
        return sectionIsExpanded[section] ? (sectiondata.workoutType.count + 1) : 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AddWorkoutTemplateHeaderTableViewCell
            let sectionData = data[indexPath.section]
            headerCell.headingLabel?.text = sectionData.folderName
            
            if sectionIsExpanded[indexPath.section] {
                headerCell.setExpanded()
            } else {
                headerCell.setCollapsed()
            }
            return headerCell
        } else {
            let catCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AddWorkoutCategoryTableViewCell
            let sectionData = data[indexPath.section]
            let rowData = sectionData.workoutType[(indexPath.row - 1)]
           
            catCell.headingLabel?.text = rowData.workoutCategoryName
            var subHeadings = ""
            for item in rowData.totalWorkouts {
                subHeadings = subHeadings + item.workoutName + ", "
            }
            
            
            catCell.mutiWorkoutLabel?.text = subHeadings
            return catCell
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Expand/hide the section if tapped its header
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            sectionIsExpanded[indexPath.section] = !sectionIsExpanded[indexPath.section]
            
            tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you have "common" elements -- the chevron image, the title, the `...` and the "Start workout" button, I would suggest a single cell class instead of separate classes.

Put the "center" elements in a Vertical Stack View:

[image]

When you want to show the cell "collapsed" set:

```
collapsedView.isHidden = false
expandedView.isHidden = true
```

and to show the cell "expanded":

```
collapsedView.isHidden = true
expandedView.isHidden = false
```

The stack view will automatically remove the space occupied by the hidden view, but leaving it as part of the view hierarchy so you don't have to add / remove subviews and activate / deactivate constraints.

This is a sample layout:

[image]

and how it looks at run-time:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @DonMag I have achieved more likely to your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  AddWorkoutViewController.swift

//
//  Created by developer on 6/1/21.
//

import UIKit

class AddWorkoutViewController: UIViewController, passIndexData {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView?
    var data = [WorkoutTemplate]()
    var sectionIsExpanded = [false, false, false]
    private let headerIdentifier = "WorkoutTemplateHeaderCell"
    private let cellIdentifier = "AddWorkoutCategoryCell"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let workout = Workout(workoutName: "Squat", reps: 10, sets: 9)
        let workout2 = Workout(workoutName: "Bench press", reps: 6, sets: 7)
        let workout3 = Workout(workoutName: "Dunmbell lunge", reps: 12, sets: 78)
        
        let workoutType = WorkoutType(workoutCategoryName: "Basic full body", totalWorkouts: [workout, workout2, workout3])
        let workoutType2 = WorkoutType(workoutCategoryName: "Basic full body", totalWorkouts: [workout, workout2, workout3])
        
        let workoutTemplate = WorkoutTemplate(folderName: "My Workout Template", workoutType: [workoutType, workoutType2])
        
        let workoutType3 = WorkoutType(workoutCategoryName: "Basic full body", totalWorkouts: [workout, workout2, workout3])
        let workoutType4 = WorkoutType(workoutCategoryName: "Basic full body", totalWorkouts: [workout, workout2, workout3])
        
        
        let workoutTemplate2 = WorkoutTemplate(folderName: "My Workout Template", workoutType: [workoutType3, workoutType4])
        
        data.append(workoutTemplate)
        data.append(workoutTemplate2)
        //data.append(workoutTemplate)
        
        tableView?.reloadData()
        
        
    }
    
    func stringToAtributedString(string:String, fontName: String, alpha: CGFloat = 1)-> NSMutableAttributedString {
        if let safeFont = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 14) {
            let color = UIColor(named: "textBlack")
            color?.withAlphaComponent(alpha)
            let attribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: safeFont, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color]
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attribute)
            return attributedString
        }
        return NSMutableAttributedString()
        
    }

}

extension AddWorkoutViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.2 //.leastNormalMagnitude // 0 may not work
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // First will always be header
        let sectiondata = data[section]
        return sectionIsExpanded[section] ? (sectiondata.workoutType.count + 1) : 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            // header cell
            let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AddWorkoutTemplateHeaderTableViewCell
            let sectionData = data[indexPath.section]
            headerCell.headingLabel?.text = sectionData.folderName
            
            if sectionIsExpanded[indexPath.section] {
                headerCell.setExpanded()
            } else {
                headerCell.setCollapsed()
            }
            headerCell.selectionStyle = .none
            return headerCell
        } else {
            // workout category cell
            let catCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AddWorkoutCategoryTableViewCell
            let sectionData = data[indexPath.section]
            let rowData = sectionData.workoutType[(indexPath.row - 1)]
           
            catCell.headingLabel?.text = rowData.workoutCategoryName
            var subHeadings = ""
            
            let workoutNames = UILabel()
            workoutNames.numberOfLines = 0
            workoutNames.alpha = 0.7
            
            for item in rowData.totalWorkouts {
                subHeadings = subHeadings + item.workoutName + ", "
            }
            
            
            
            workoutNames.attributedText = stringToAtributedString(string: subHeadings, fontName: "Poppins-Regular")
            
            if catCell.workoutSetContainer != nil {
                for view in catCell.workoutSetContainer!.subviews.enumerated() {
                    view.element.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
                        
            print("section: \(indexPath.section) row: \(indexPath.row) rowCollapse: \(rowData.isExpanded)")
            
            
            if rowData.isExpanded {
                catCell.setCollapsed()
                for item in rowData.totalWorkouts.enumerated() {
                    let workoutSetcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WorkoutSetCell") as! AddworkoutWOrkoutSetTableViewCell
                    workoutSetcell.workoutNameLabel?.text = item.element.workoutName
                    //workoutSetcell.workoutSetLabel?.text = "\(item.element.reps)" + " " + "\(item.element.sets)"
                    
                    let repsCount = stringToAtributedString(string: "\(item.element.reps)", fontName: "Poppins-Bold")
                    let repsString = stringToAtributedString(string: " reps", fontName: "Poppins-Regular", alpha: 0.7)
                    
                    
                    repsCount.append(repsString)
                    workoutSetcell.workoutSetLabel?.attributedText = repsCount
                    
                    

                    catCell.workoutSetContainer?.addArrangedSubview(workoutSetcell)
                }
                
            } else {
                catCell.setExpanded()
                catCell.workoutSetContainer?.addArrangedSubview(workoutNames)

            }
            
            catCell.cellDelegate = self
            catCell.cellIndexPath = indexPath
            catCell.selectionStyle = .none
            return catCell
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Expand/hide the section if tapped its header
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            sectionIsExpanded[indexPath.section] = !sectionIsExpanded[indexPath.section]
            
            tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .automatic)
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
}

extension AddWorkoutViewController:expandCell {
    func passIndexValues(indexPath: IndexPath?) {
        if indexPath != nil {
            let sectionData = data[indexPath!.section]
            let rowData = sectionData.workoutType[indexPath!.row - 1]
            rowData.isExpanded = !rowData.isExpanded
            sectionData.workoutType[indexPath!.row - 1] = rowData
            data[indexPath!.section] = sectionData

            tableView?.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
            //tableView?.reloadData()
        }
        
        //print("index path \(indexPath?.section)")
    }
    
    
    
}
```